# Import .dmp file into oracle developer with data pump import wizard

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new in oracle , I have got an error when I want to import .dmp file path into the wizard oracle developer . I know this correct command but I want learn with wizard, so please help me but do not mentioned me with correct command , as I said I know the command in linux ,I want to learn with wizard .
I choose DBA in view  in menu ,after that I right click the admin I choose then I click data pump then I choose the wizard for pump . Its Necessary you know I create 4 schema and I want this dumpfile into  4 schema .so when I click next until I go to choose this type and location of my file but I click next ,the next page any one schema show me , so please help me .[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ8jl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAR2F.png)

I wat to import my .dmp file . please help me . I got error : ORA - 31640 . unable to open dump file